# Change the text string of a cell based on whether or not previous cells are filled

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, automation

I am working on a spreadsheet that tracks the overall pipeline for video production for a group of volunteer filmers and editors. Being on as a volunteer manager myself, I wanted to create a spreadsheet to track the progress of these different groups.

I want to automate as much of this page as I can for everyone's convenience, including myself, so we can quickly look at the progress of each video. (I am still working on the conditional formatting)

[image: Pipeline Picture 1]

At the end of the spreadsheet, I have a cell dedicated to listing what phase of production each video is in. (as noted in the picture as the "Phase Information" column.)

[image]

My main question is: Is there a way to automate this? For example, when all of the information is filled out for a specific phase (i.e. Phase I, Phase II, Phase III, etc.,) the sheet automatically updates the cell at the end of the row, allowing me to use this information in different parts of the overall spreadsheet.

Any help with this project would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.